# How do I tell my interviewer that I need more time for school?

Tags: interviewing, communication

I am being interviewed this week, and they mentioned that they have an "immediate opening" - but the issue is that, I need an extra semester for school(grad. school, where I need to complete thesis)!

How do I break it to the interviewer that i'm still in school for at least 2 more months.

I'd rather play it safe. But would it also be OK to play along and see if I get an offer, then negotiate about starting date?

Comment: Tell them early.  They may hold the position for you.  If not, they may be willing to offer you a position in the future if something becomes available.  However, if you wait until they offer to tell them you need 8+ weeks before you can start...they're likely to be angry.

Comment: @notmyrealname - OK understood, I'll do so/! Thank You Very Much

Comment: This is one reason having an objective on a resume can be helpful, it is a natural way to start this conversation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Having something like "Seeking full-time employment beginning December, 2013" as part of a short objective has been incredibly beneficial to me in the past, especially at career fairs or other places you discuss your resume, including interviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as both Joe & notmyrealname said, I need to give full disclosure.

And I did just send an email to the HR person. It was a little painful to type, but yes - I should not be shy to tell them the whole story, just in case they would not even entertain me if I'm not ready to start immediately in the next week.

Thank You everyone.