# Negotiating joining date with future employer due to extended notice period

Tags: professionalism, resignation, human-resources, india, relieving-letter

**I wanted to know how to deal and negotiate with new employer regarding joining date and required leaves few days after joining.**

I tried all i can with my current employer to not get notice period extended but now it seems to get the relieving letter and F&F, etc i have to serve extended days and also for easy transition of work handover.

Current notice period is 2months. Extension is of 10 days.

Problem 1: If i get relieved under extended notice days then i would get no break between job change and have to join from next working days.
I had given tentative dates keeping buffer days for getting break but seems my notice period has gone even ahead of the kept buffer period.

Problem 2: I will need two leaves after joining new company within next 2 weeks for exams of distance learning program i am pursuing ( they already they know about my pursuance but not about upcoming exam of the course and i came to know the schedule of exam today itself)

### Update regarding extension of notice period

The key person who had to conclude exit date was busy in his personal matters and then in other projects under company. Now after almost 20 days of putting letter he has concluded after my repeated attempts to get Exit date.

### Background story

10 months before company did some technology certification for three employees due to cost incurred company got certified employee sign bonds of 12 months but i was exempted from signing bond somehow (Due to reason HR or gods knows). Note that I was promoted for going for certification at last minute because one person was not well and was hospitalised. As i am leaving and having not signed bond but implied bond period to other two employees, my manager is asking for extension to compensate a bit and ignoring the reality. Might be manager is thinking that my future employer withdraw the offer due extension in notice period and so that he can retain me for few more months. Also note that my current employer asked for 3months +2 months  notice due to bond things explained above but now settled for 10 days extension but with no fixed assurance on exit date even after sharing KT plans and past experience of new team member's KT.

### Update

New job location is in different city so there is some relocation stuff also involved.

Comment: Related (not duplicate) Question: [How can I prevent a notice period from being unreasonably extended?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13193/16)

Comment: Is there some option that gives them the right to extend your notice period in your contract or something?  How are they allowed to extend it like this?

Comment: Also Related: [How do I tell my interviewer that I need more time for school?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12458/16)

Comment: Many people go right from one job to the next with no break, why would that be a problem?

Comment: @HLGEM what about 2nd problem then ?

Comment: Check updated question.. @Chad

Comment: I assume the rules in India are different but within the US once I provide a notice stating I'm leaving with a timeline, it's up to my digression if I allow it to be extended, and refusing an extension is typically not considered unprofessional. I realize India is probably different but I'd assume a company can't just force extensions onto your leave notice.

Comment: Instead of negotiating with the new company, you could just tell them the facts: "My old employer wants to extend my notice period by ten days", and their HR department, which wants you to start on time, might know exactly what you need to say to your old employer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just say NO.  You owe no obligation to your current employer.  In my opinion he is clearly trying to sabotage your new offer.

2 months is a huge notice period anyway.  This may be common in some parts of the world, but in the US 2 weeks is normal and almost always enough.

I have given notice about 8 times over a 20 year work history.  Only once was 2 weeks too short to transition, and usually it was too long.  My last change, due to vacation timing, I actually only gave 1 week notice.  They didn't like it, but knew my situation and accepted it.

You should stick to your notice, you are under no legal obligation. The only downside I see is them letting you go too early.  In that case you could potentially speak to your new employer about starting early.